# Could an artificial neural network algorithm be expressed in terms of map-reduce operations?

Tags: parallel-computing, artificial-intelligence, neural-networks

Could an artificial neural network algorithm be expressed in terms of map-reduce operations? I am also interested more generally in methods of parallelization as applied to ANNs and their application to cloud computing.

I would think one approach would involve running a full ANN on each node and somehow integrating the results in order to treat the grid like a single entity (in terms of input/output and machine learning characteristics.) I would be curious even in this case what such an integrating strategy might look like.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes it can, and has been. In the paper [Map-Reduce for Machine Learning on Multicore](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/3150-map-reduce-for-machine-learning-on-multicore.pdf) they discuss using the Map-Reduce paradigm for several common ML algorithms including ANNs.

Comment: Thanks! +1 and accepted -- this paper is a great resource.

Comment: The link now 404s :(

Comment: @JosephWeissman link should work now.